# Different result in RoundingMode.HALF_UP

Tags: java

Please comment me freely. What was wrong in the following program. It is giving different round result.

```
public class Test {
    public static String round(double value, int places) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.toPlainString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        double value1 = 1.1234565;
        System.out.println(round(value1, 6));
        double value2 = 1.1235;
        System.out.println(round(value2, 3));
    }
}
```

Why it is out put like that?

```
1.123457
1.123   --> Actually, I expect 1.124
```

In Doc(eclipse)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're calling the [`BigDecimal(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal-double-) constructor. That's documented as:

> Translates a double into a BigDecimal which is the exact decimal representation of the double's binary floating-point value. The scale of the returned BigDecimal is the smallest value such that (10scale × val) is an integer.

The notes are illuminating too, and I suggest you read them.

The value you're passing in is exactly 1.12349999999999994315658113919198513031005859375, as that's the closest `double` to 1.1235. You can see that if you print out `bd.toPlainString()` before calling `setScale`. Therefore, that *isn't* half-way between 1.123 and 1.124 - it's closest to 1.123.

If you want a `BigDecimal` value of *exactly* 1.1235, I suggest you pass it as a `String` instead:

```
import java.math.*;

public class Test {
    public static String round(String value, int places) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.toPlainString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String value1 = "1.1234565";
        System.out.println(round(value1, 6));
        String value2 = "1.1235";
        System.out.println(round(value2, 3));
    }
}
```

Alternatively you could use `BigDecimal.valueOf(double)` instead of `new BigDecimal(double)` - but then you still have the problem that you've converted your *real* original source data (the text in your source code) into a binary floating point number first, potentially losing information.

Comment: You only lose information with `BigDecimal.valueOf` if you get a different value if you do `Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(string))` if this conversion if lossless, `double` is fine.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I have to use parsed double String

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, but how easily can you tell that from looking at source code? I prefer not to play chicken with the compiler :) If what you're really interested in is a sequence of decimal digits (and a decimal separator) then out of the compile-time constants available, I think a string is the best choice.

Comment: @JonSkeet this is true if you have no idea how many digits you might be inputting and in this case it *really* matters exactly how it will round the value.  However, if you have some idea that the number of digits after rounding is less than 15, and most sane number are e.g. money, you don't have a problem.  If Java had a `decimal` type like C# it wouldn't be such an issue as the language has native support, but misuse of `BigDecimal` leads to as many but more subtle bugs than using double IMHO.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, I suspect it would rarely be a problem in reality - but it just feels like using `double` is a fundamentally broken way of representing a sequence of decimal digits. I'd certainly agree that `BigDecimal` can lead to some other interesting problems - as can `decimal` in C#, of course... what a pity it is that numbers are surprisingly hard. Not like text of course, which is entirely straightforward ;)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using to exact represention of the `double` including any representation error. A simple solution is to use the value you would get from the `double` if it was printed.

```
public static String round(double value, int places) {
    return BigDecimal.valueOf(value)
                     .setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                     .toPlainString();
}
```

`BigDecimal.valueOf` uses the simplest value which would be represented as the `double` you have.